# TikZ: clipping nodes outside current picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to clip a node that is outside the current picture. (I do this so that I can re-use a relatively complicated TikZ picture that I use several times in different places.) I can't get it to work, however. The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[clip] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[red] (1,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to achieve the same effect as if I had a single tikzpicture environment and moved the fill command just below the draw command:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[clip] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\fill[red] (1,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I tried the "remember picture" option without success. If this cannot be made to work, I can refactor my TikZ picture and use the `\input` command. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So you would like to move the clipped content to different place ? Also you mention nodes but I don't see how they enter the question.

Comment: In the above MWE, I don't define nodes, but in my proper code I define nodes and then try to clip around them. Yes, in a sense I want to move the clipped content to a different place - just for convenience.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but couldn't you just define a command containing the relevent code and then use this where ever you like?

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\reusable}%
{   \draw (0,0) circle (1cm+\pgflinewidth/2);
    \clip (0,0) circle (1cm);%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \reusable
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \reusable
  \fill[red] (1,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]